# How to import a VS MasterPage in Ektron

Tags: c#, asp.net, ektron

I recently installed a new site in Ektron. It created all the folders and files necessary to have it working. I created a custom MasterPage in VS 2012 with own folders and CSS/Script files and looking to import it into Ektron to use.

I imported from Workarea > Settings > Template and import template.

When I click on View for the template, I am seeing the following error:

```
Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'WMED.Site'.

Source Error: 



Line 1:  <%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="WMED.Site" %>
Line 2:  
Line 3:  


 Source File:  /Site.Master    Line:  1
```

How do I resolve the error

:: Should I remove the `inherit` and `namespace` from the MP for it to work?

The `HEAD`:

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
    <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="True" />
    <meta name="MobileOptimized" content="320" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/gif" href="favicon.gif" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="theScripts/sliderJS.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="theStyles/sliderStyle.css" type="text/css" />-->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="theStyles/pageStyle.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="theCustomFonts/trajanpro_style.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="theCustomFonts/blackjar_style.css" type="text/css" />
    <script src="theScripts/jquery.webticker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="theStyles/tickerStyles.css" type="text/css" />
    <script src="theScripts/pageScript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="theScripts/placeholders.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="theScripts/jquery.sidr.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="theStyles/jquery.sidr.light.css" type="text/css" />

    <script src="theScripts/jssor.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="theScripts/jssor.slider.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="theScripts/jssorSlider.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="theStyles/jssorSlider.css" type="text/css" />

    <!-- ENSURES HTML TAGS ARE COMPLIANT -->
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="theStyles/styleDiagnostic.css" type="text/css" />-->

    <script>
        $(window).resize(function () {
            var docHeight = $(document).height();
            var docWidth = $(document).width();
            $('#lbl').text("height: " + docHeight + " width: " + docWidth);
        });
    </script>
    <script>
        function SearchNMClick() {
            document.getElementById('HiddenSearchNM').click();
        }
    </script>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadPlaceHolder" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably using a Web Application project opposed to a Web Site.  Because of this, the code for your MasterPages, ASPX templates, wireframes...etc. is compiled into a DLL (or DLLs) when you build the project.

When you deploy your Web Application project to your Ektron site, in additional to the files you've already pushed out, you have to copy your project's DLLs into the bin directory of the site.  Your project will have a bin directory after building where you can find these, just look in File Explorer to find it if you don't see it.

**/bin/WMED.dll**

Also, if this is the case, do **not** push your `.cs` files to the server.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I changed `CodeBehind` to `CodeFile` and I am able to see the site but none of the scripts are loading :/

Comment: OK, if you're now using CodeFile opposed to CodeBehind, you DO need to have your .cs files on the server with your .master, .aspx, .ascx...etc.

Comment: How are your scripts getting added to the page?  Can we see the code?

Comment: I updated my question with the entire HEAD section for the MasterPage. The scripts/styles are in the correct folder from ROOT directory of my site.

Comment: Add a '/' to the beginning of your paths, aliased URLs will screw things up.  Example: "/theScripts/pageScript.js" instead of "theScripts/pageScript.js"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62681/discussion-between-fooser-and-searchforknowledge).

Comment: Please help me one more time :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26303362/how-do-display-a-cms-collection-in-an-asp-net-page-using-an-xslt-file

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to import a MasterPage into Ektron, only ASPX templates are imported.  The process is, create your ASPX template (with associated MasterPage), save it into your website and then register it with Ektron.

Comment: Ok so what I did was create a Default.aspx (associate it with the MP) and a Site.Master MP and copied those two files and any folder which is required by those two pages into the Ektron site folder and then imported the Default.aspx as a Wireframe Template but everytime I click "View" to view it, it keeps giving me a blank screen. Am I doing it the right way?

Answer (score 1):

Check the master page's code behind file (the .cs) and make sure that the public partial class looks like public partial class WMED.Sitename is using the same. Also make sure that the .cs file is located in the same directory as the .master template.

Comment: Do I have to change `CodeBehind` to `CodeFile`? I double and triple checked and they are the same. The Default.aspx (used for the wireframe template) is in the same root folder as the MasterPage.

Comment: If you are using a compiled site then it will use CodeBehind. If you are running uncompiled then you would use CodeFile.

Comment: I had to use CodeFile because it wasn't compiled and thank you for clarifying :)